# How to create a Ptr Word8 for ByteString

Tags: pointers, haskell, null, bytestring

[create](https://github.com/haskell/bytestring/blob/master/Data/ByteString/Internal.hs#L39), from Data.ByteString.Internal, states that it needs a `Ptr Word8` in order to create a ByteString. I'm guessing this is like a reference to the head of the bytestring or something. However, I'm not sure what I should use to create a new pointer - I'm fairly sure it's not done properly with [nullPtr](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-9.6/base-4.9.1.0/Foreign-Ptr.html#v:nullPtr).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `create` gives you a pointer to a memory to fill:

```
create :: Int -> (Ptr Word8 -> IO ()) -> IO ByteString
```

The first argument is the length of bytestring to create, the second is a function, that fills the bytestring. Basically `create` allocates memory buffer of the specified size, then calls the function with the pointer to the buffer. Usage example:

```
> create 5 $ \ptr -> pokeArray ptr [65, 66, 67, 68, 69]
"ABCDE"
```